# Binding two textbox keep synchronized using caliburn.micro c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, textbox, caliburn.micro

I use Caliburn.Micro and WPF.
The View's name is : NewPlayView and the ViewModel's name is : NewPlayViewModel.

I have two textbox, I would like that by changing the value of textbox1, the value of textbox2 various accordingly. For example, if I put 10 in textbox1, textbox2 displays in 20 (10 * 2).

```
 <TextBox Height="22" HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="textbox1"/>
 <TextBox Height="22" HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="textbox2"/>
```

What i can do this ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you either create 2 properties in your `NewPlayViewModel` model, lets say `Value1` and `Value2` and you bind them accordingly:

```
<TextBox Height="22" HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="textbox1" Text="{Binding Path=Value1}"/>
<TextBox Height="22" HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="textbox2" Text="{Binding Path=Value2}"/>
```

and when `Value1` changes you recalculate `Value2` (or vice versa) and [notify](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) UI that both values have changed

or you keep just one property, for example `Value`, create custom [`IValueConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx), implement both `Convert` and `ConvertBack` methods with your algorithm and bind it like this:

```
<TextBox Height="22" HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="textbox1" Text="{Binding Path=Value}"/>
<TextBox Height="22" HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="textbox2" Text="{Binding Path=Value, Converter={StaticResource MyValueConverter}}"/>
```

Comment: Absolutely correct and i prefer the first choice so i don't need one more converter and guys this is not specific to Caliburn.Micro, this is pure WPF principles. CM doesn't have anything to do with this.

Comment: OK **THANKS** !  I will use the first tip, but how the method will work to change the value whenever I put a different value in the textbox? Can you kindly show me an _example_ of code?  thanks again

Comment: [this](http://db.tt/6l6I4WvC) is my example. It implements both solutions so you can see and choose. Personally I prefer one with converter.